# How to read a multiple string input in form of an function?

Tags: c++, function, input, cin

I have a task to get user input in this form:

```
"SEND name1 name2"
```

The goal is to find the shortest path between the names, but that currently not the problem. I don't know how to read multiple strings form a single input.

The first string would be SEND, but that's the easiest one. How do I read the other two? After getting the names, I'd pass them on to a function to find out the distance between them.